# Use Mathematica to plot the flow of an ODE with discontinuity

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, numerical-integration, numerics

How can I use Mathematica to plot the flow of the following ODE in $\mathbb R$?
$$\frac{d}{dt} X(t,x) = \chi_{\{x>0\}}(X(t,x)),  t \in [0,T],$$
$X(0,x) = x,  x \in \mathbb R$

where $\chi$ denotes the [indicator function of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

I know about the command `NDSolve`, but is it applicable in this situation given the discontinuity in the source term? And I'd be mostly interested in rendering a nice picture of the flow.

Note that a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/329913/solution-of-ode-with-discontinuity) was posed on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

```
T = 1;
Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == Boole[X[t] > 0], X[0] == x}, X, {t, 0, T}, {x}];
Show[
 Table[
  ParametricPlot[{Y[x][t], t}, {t, 0, T}],
  {x, -1, 1, 0.1}
  ],
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t"}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, this is why I like Iverson brackets more than indicator functions; I find the latter more confusing to parse in general, whereas the `Boole[]` expression is concise and clear.

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks very nice. It seems that there may be a nonuniqueness problem for trajectories starting at $x=0$. How does one identify in this picture the unique flow in the sense of DiPerna-Lions (http://php.math.unifi.it/users/cime/Courses/2005/02/CIME-2005-Ambrosio-Lecture_Notes.pdf)?

Comment: No, there is no nonuniqueness problem in thi case: For initial condition  `x>0`, the right branch is taken and the left one for `z <= 0`.